# Creating new action for preview of Aggregation not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My app's Opengraph location is

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/141573619260829/opengraph

I can't create a new action on preview of Aggregation.
Details-
I can't submit my action "add".It says  No Aggregations created for this Action Type but i have already created a Aggregation for add but when previewing I'm having a problem.I clicked "Add New" under Preview Actions: sector & I filled spaces with data & clicked create but it says Oops Something is wrong(when i filled with wrong data it displays the problem but when i filled all correctly it this plays Oops Something is wrong. Is this a know bug? please help me to solve this..